# How to Pause ALL CSS animations?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

How would I go about pausing all css animations in a document at start? I want to have a class on all the elements that contain css animations at start, ie: '.paused'. Then, using a call back in my js using jQuery, remove the class '.paused', then add a class to resume playing, ie: '.running'.

Here is what I've got:

HTML:

```
<li class="firstanimation paused">...</li>
<li class="secondanimation paused">...</li>
<li class="thirdanimation paused">...</li>
```

CSS:

```
#slider li.paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#slider li.firstanimation {
    animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;-moz-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;-webkit-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.secondanimation {
    animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;-moz-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;-webkit-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.thirdanimation {
    animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;-moz-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;-webkit-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
}
```

So, my problem is that the "#slider li.paused" selector doesn't work. In Chrome, the inspector says the 'animation-play-state:paused;' is an invalid property value...? I dont get that because I also have this in my css and it works fine:

```
#slider:hover li, #slider:hover .progress-bar {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

So again, basically in a nutshell, how do I target all my animations with a class to have them all be paused? [According to W3 docs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation-shorthand-property), animation-play-state: paused; "Applies To: all elements, ::before and ::after pseudo-elements." But it doesnt in my case. What do I have wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thnx!

Comment: Instead of adding `.paused` to each element, you could add it to `#slider` and use `#slider.paused li {animation-play-state: paused}`

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to effect a change for the entire document, it's probably better to add/remove the "paused" class on the `<body>` object and then make your CSS rules be `.paused #slider ... {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to selector specificity. Since the both the `.paused` and `li.elemclass` have the same specificity, the compiler will always choose the last one

To fix it you can move the `.paused` properties after the others or make it have more precedence by adding another layer, something like `body #slider li.paused`

[Check the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) for more info on specificity and [here's a specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for your convenience

Comment: But other rules don't have `animation-play-state` property, so it shouldn't be overridden, should it?

Comment: @Oriol It defaults to `animation-play-state:running`, I *would think* that'd be enough. We'll have to see from the OP

Comment: @Zach Saucier Thnx.  I knew better and I don't know why I had it at the top. LOL